# Persist Flutter widget in memory

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I've created my own simple bottom nav bar implementation in Flutter. When a tab is pressed, Flutter is currently re-creating the widget (`initState()` gets called every time) which is non-desirable.

I want the widgets to be persisted in memory so if they've already been created, they're simply popped straight in.

*Main Widget*

```
class _MainRootScreenState extends State<MainRootScreen> {

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  List<Widget> _screens;

  @override
  void initState() {

    // load pages
    _screens = [
      PageOne(),
      PageTwo(),
      PageThree()
    ];

    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: _screens[_selectedIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomTabBar(context)
    );
  }
}
```

so when `_selectedIndex` gets updated, the selected page is getting re-created.

I've tried using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` on the pages with no luck.

Comment: `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` only works within a `Scrollable`. You don't have any here

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your widget/page should not rebuild when you click on tab button. You just need to follow this code

just add `State<PageOne> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<PageOne>` to your state class. after this you need to override a method called `wantKeepAlive` and make `wantKeepAlive` as true that's it.

By default `wantKeepAlive` is false because of it saves our memory .

**PageOne**

```
class PageOne extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageOneState createState() => _PageOneState();
}
class _PageOneState extends State<PageOne> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<PageOne> {

  // Your code are here

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Do the same from **pageTwo** and **PageThree** also that's it

Comment: tried this with no luck unfortunately. @rémi-rousselet mentioned above that this only works within a `Scrollable`